# testing choroplethr and choroplethrmaps in Hong Kong Map

Tags: google-maps, choropleth, choroplethr

I am testing choroplethr and choroplethrmaps in Hong Kong Map.
I want to show the region in Hong Kong and the vote. 
following is what I have done in R.
But it does not work.
Could you help me how can I do it?

```
install.packages(c("choroplethr", "choroplethrMaps"))
library(choroplethr)
setwd('/Users/hkawngnaw/Downloads')
hkmap <- readRDS("HKG_adm1.rds")
map(hkmap)
hkelection<-data.frame(c('Central and Western','Wan Chai','Eastern','Southern','Yau Tsim Mong','Sham Shui Po','Kowloon City','North','Tai Po','Sai kung','Sha Tin'))
hkelection$VOTE<-c(23307,14165,67685,32023,24907,11395,42691,27193,34183,45697,76686)
colnames<-c('Region','Value')
allcandidates$Region = allcandidates$Value
state_choropleth(allcandidates)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

The main issue is that the function `state_choropleth` is designed to map US States, but you are giving it data to map Hong Kong administrative regions. You can see this by reading the help for the function `state_choropleth`. You can do that by typing `?state_choropleth`.

Choroplethr can indeed map Hong Kong subdivisions. But to use that functionality, you need to use the function `?admin1_choropleth`. That function is in the package [choroplethrAdmin1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethrAdmin1/index.html). [Here](https://arilamstein.com/open-source/choroplethr/creating-administrative-level-1-maps/) is some documentation on how that package works.

Lastly, the code snippet that you included in your question is not reproducible. It includes setting the working directory to a directory that I don't have, and loading a file that I don't have. In the future, I recommend making your question "reproducible". You can learn more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610).